# How to Know if a Movie/Show is Translated Well Enough to Help in Language Learning?

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, german

As addressed in questions like [*this*](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/335/how-can-watching-movies-help-improve-fluency-and-listening-skill), watching movies and shows in your target language can be a good way to practice your listening skills, while also being exposed to new vocabulary and spoken grammar in a language. I personally have been considering trying this technique with movies/shows I am already familiar with so that I don't need to catch every detail to follow the plot and can just focus on picking up what I can through the context I already know.

The main problem I foresee with this idea, and why I haven't tried it yet, is I have no way of verifying if any particular movie/show/production company have taken the time to accurately translate into the different languages. There are countless examples in media of awkward conjugation that you'd never hear in real conversation or even translations that are flat out wrong, and I worry as someone who doesn't have too extensive of a background in a language I may pick up bad habits or false information from a poorly translated work.

---

I know more specific info is preferred with Stack Exchange sites, so I will note I am currently working on learning German, and was considering starting with children/family based content such as Disney works (as I am familiar with those and know they are translated into several languages, not just my current target), but if there are any generalized resources or tips people know of those answers are also appreciated.

Comment: What has the translation got to do with learning the language? The translation method of language learning is mostly a very bad way to go. Don't use stuff that is translated. Use stuff in the original language, like German, and turn on the closed captions in German.

Comment: @Lambie while I understand anything that is written in the original language will be vastly better, I was hoping to start with movies that I am already familiar with as I don’t have a ton of vocabulary yet and I thought that if I already knew the plot I would have a better chance connecting the German words to what is happening. I understand that no translations are going to be perfect but some are good enough that people in other countries will still watch and enjoy those translated movies despite them having originally been written in English.

Comment: I am so **confused** by what you are saying. A good translation will not help you "connect to German words". That's just nuts. Only German closed captions will.

Comment: Please read this blog post for why translation does not work for learning a language: https://learnjam.com/translation-doesnt-teach-language/

Comment: @Lambie I still fully intend to watch the movie in German with German close-captions, I just was interested in watching a movie that I already knew that happened to be originally written in English. If it were a movie I had never seen and I’m watching it in German with German CC I’m not sure if be able to follow well enough to really learn much, and thought that if I knew the plot I would better be able to comprehend their German words as I would know roughly what is being conveyed and could use the known context to fill in the gaps to understand the unknown words.

Comment: Knowing a plot does not help learn a language. Your fill-in-the-gap idea does not work. You'd be better off just reading and repeating the German **even if you don't understand every word**, and also writing stuff down to look up later.

Comment: Personally, as a learner, I found watching old Star Trek series (e.g. DS9, Voyager) in German to be very useful, since I know those shows. German voice acting is quite good, but it should be noted that the voice actors are making trade-offs in accuracy to make their native language phrase more natural and to make it match the timing of the original actors. Usually, if you read the subtitles (e.g. German), the translation is more accurate, but it won't match the dubbing version for the same reason -- the writers of the captions are making their own trade-offs to make it easier (faster) to read.

Comment: But it's still not as good as watching "authentic" material. As an example, in German films/shows, there is sometimes some on-screen situation where characters decide whether to "duzen" rather than "Siezen" -- as a learner I found such interactions interesting because we have no such conversations like that in English language discourse. Anyway, in dubbed content you're obviously never going to hear an interaction like that. The dubbers/translators just made their own choice of which form (Siezen or duzen), and quite often the voice actors make a different choice than the written translators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having German as my native langugage, you might find my personal experiences useful, regarding both the quality of German movie/show dubbing as well as the usefulness for language learning.

Regarding movies/shows dubbed in German, the vast majority uses correct expressions, just as native speakers would do. No surprise, the dubbing is done by native speakers, so they wouldn't create awkward dialogs (or at least not more awkward than the original ones).

But of course, characters in movies might not be your role models, so the way they act and speak might not match your personality. E.g. learning German from the villain of some B-movie or from Donald Duck might not be a good idea unless you want to sound like such a weirdo.

Regarding the exactness of translations, you'll find that roughly the same ideas are conveyed, but the dubbed version never is as exact as you'd expect it in e.g. literature. Dubbing aims to be lip-synchronous, so that the audio more or less matches the lips movement you see. And this makes exact translations impossible.

Personally, I have used dubbed versions of my favorite shows when learning foreign languages (e.g. the Polish version of StarTrek Voyager), and it was both fun and helpful.

My recommendation is to go ahead, select some movies or shows that you know to use an acceptable language level, and watch the German-dubbed versions.

Comment: Native speakers with no training in translation can make terrible mistakes when dubbing. And if you are trying to learn German, why would you watch something dubbed in German instead of something originally in German? Dubbing depends on the number of spaces allocated for it. Not on lips synching.

Comment: @Lambie _why would you watch something dubbed in German instead of something originally in German?_ - because if you do only German original at some time you get fed up

Comment: @Andra I have **no idea** what you are trying to say. In trying to learn a language, any language at all, I would only be interested in watching works in the that language.

Comment: @Lambie People are different. As I said in my answer, I enjoyed watching a Polish-dubbed version of StarTrek Voyager.

Comment: I am getting slightly fed up with this. Dubbed movies is not a way to learn a language. You can enjoy anything you like. But if you want to learn a language like Japanese, watch something originally in Japanese, not something translated into Japanese. What is the point of even talking about this?

Comment: @Lambie I understand your frustrated here but I think you're missing the bigger picture. Obviously watching/reading stories that were originally written in a German is going to be a better representation of that German, no one is debating that. The benefit others see in engaging with content that has been translated is there can be a baseline understanding of the content that can help with comprehension in your early days with a language. Even things like knowing what words are just names mean you don't have to waste time trying to figure out an unknown word that isn't useful to your learning.

Comment: @Lambie Additionally, if you had typed up an answer explaining either your personal experiences and/or attached the research you are aware of, I and others could have engaged with it more and possibly preferred yours over this answer. But as it stands with only comments stating your thoughts on this subject matter there is really no truly impactful way to engage with your statements beyond and upvote to a comments that tend to get buried.

Comment: @gabbo1092 The question is naive. No serious learner uses dubbed movies to learn a language. That is why I didn't bother with an answer. There is no "research" to back this up. It is just an obvious thing. Why use something dubbed when you can use something that is in the original language you are trying to learn??

Answer (score -2):

One potential solution is to hire a freelance translator on upwork.com or a similair such website.

If you download the movie file subtitles written in German (Deutsch), you can send the subtitles to a friend or freelance translator who is fluent in Deutsch.